# How can I navigate to the same XAML page in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I need to navigate to the same XAML page in a UWP app. How can I do this?

I've read other answers here on simply passing in a parameter to the URI; however, I am not using `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri())`. In my example, we are using `NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(UserSelectionPage), theParameterObject)`.

I also understand using observable properties with `NotificationChanged` events could accomplish this, but I want to keep both passes to this page in the backstack. In short, I want this:

> HomePage -> UserSelectionPage (pass1) -> UserSelectionPage (pass2) ->
>   ConfirmPage

And I need to keep both passes of the UserSelectionPage in the backstack.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Why would you want a page to navigate to itself?

Comment: On the HomePage, the user designates a number (up to 3) for the number of notifications they want to receive, let's call it numberOfNotifications. The UserSelectionPage will be navigated to numberOfNotification times, allowing the user to set the same set of attributes (present on the UserSelectionPage) for each notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that navigation to the same page is possible in UWP. I needed to be sure that the parameters being passed were not identical objects. Adding this check solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well navigating to the same page is not possible, but you can change your logic to reuse your page.

First of all in the pass1:

The user fill the form or data, after that I guess he press next button or something like that to go to the next stage, there you need to save all data in the Local folder of you app.
The name of the setting  would be "Pass1"

Pass 2:

Clear all the values of your page or form and wait to the user to fill all the data, you need to use the same approach that I explained in the step 1, save your data in the Storage of your app with the name "Pass2"

Finally you will go to the Confirm page where you can retrieve all the data saved from the storage your settings Pass1 and Pass2.

Here is an example how to save settings in UWP apps

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData

I recommend you save all your data in a json format to sereialize and deserialize your data very easy.

Update:

Now  I know you are using MVVM Light all your viewmodels are static.

If you don't want to save your data you can create another variable of your model( I guess you have a class with all your properties) or another properties to backup the value of thes properties in the pass1 after that clear the original properties and wait for the new values in the Pass2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think I need to save form data to any app storage. Since I'm using MVVMLight, all form data is stored in view models, which I'm successfully populating for Pass2. Also, if navigating to the same page is not possible, how do you suggest I navigate to Pass2? I was unclear on this from your answer.